# Flask-SocketIO: Passing events between nodes (Redis-Adapter)

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io, flask-socketio

When using `SocketIO` in an application that runs behind a node-balancer, the official documentation states the way to pass events between those nodes (using `SocketIO-Redis`):

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

However, when using `Flask-SocketIO` (or just not using `Node.js`), the JavaScript (standalone) version of `SocketIO` will be used like this:

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

How would one implement a `Redis-Adapter` when using the  `SocketIO`-JS-standalone version? Is there anything similar that can be used without `Node.js`?

I tried to convert `SocketIO-Redis` to JavaScript using `Browserify`, but `socket.adapter()` and `io.adapter()` are both no functions. The file size has been too large, anyway.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are asking, but it seems you are treating the JS server and the JS client as if they were the same thing, but they are not. The first code example in your question uses the JS/Node Socket.IO server. The second example uses the JS Socket.IO client. There is no such thing as a "standalone" version of Socket.IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would one implement a Redis-Adapter when using the SocketIO-JS-standalone version?

I don't know why you use "standalone" here. I think you mean the JavaScript Socket.IO client, which does not have anything to do with Redis, regardless of what Socket.IO server you use.

The Redis support is implemented by the server. For the Node Socket.IO server you use the Redis-Adapter project. For the Python Socket.IO server the support for Redis comes built-in, you just need to add the `message_queue` argument when you create your server object, as shown in [the docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-multiple-workers).

Comment: I double-checked with the docs and apparently got something wrong. I wanted to point out that there is no Python version of this Redis-Adapter available because I assumed that every node would have its own message_queue and I need to pass events between them. Turns out I have everything  I need. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: The term 'standalone' was misread from https://socket.io/docs/client-api/.